# COUNTIF to display which results meet criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm working on a spreadsheet, where I'm using `COUNTIF` to check the number of times a sheet range meets a criterion. This works.

I'd like to see which cells (their contents/locations) which met the `COUNTIF` criteria.

Specifically, the cells are strings not numbers.

Comment: sounds like conditional formatting to me

Answer (score 0):

- **the best way is to use conditional formatting:**

  ---

  [image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

- **if you need formula solution use** **`ARRAYFORMULA()`**:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10<5,TRUE,FALSE))
  ```

  [image]